# Rotate SVG text around a circle then around itself using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a visual where the labels are placed by being rotated around the center of the circle. However this means that all labels on the left hand side of the circle are upside down. Is it possible to rotate the labels on the left hand side around themselves, after this rotation has taken place?

The visualisation is based on the `zoomable` sunburst from the [d3js.org](http://bl.ocks.org/vgrocha/1580af34e56ee6224d33)

The relevant code is:

```
function computeTextRotation(d) {
    var angle=(d.x +d.dx/2)*180/Math.PI - 90;
    return angle;
}

var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(partitioned_data)
        .enter().append("text")
        .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)       
        .attr("transform", function(d) {return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })    
        .attr("dx", "6") // margin
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align  
        .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
```

I tried the code below since I know this is possible if you know the `x` and `y` coordinates of the text, but it won't let me pass in `d.x` and `d.y` as the coordinates.

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
        .data(partitioned_data)
        .enter().append("text")
        .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)       
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            if (computeTextRotation(d)>90&&computeTextRotation(d)<270) {
                return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ") rotate(d.x,d.y,180)";
            } else {
                return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
            }})
        .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })    
        .attr("dx", "6") // margin
        .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align  
        .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean when you say "it wont let me pass d.x and d.y as the coordinates," but it looks like you are trying to pass in the variable *names* as strings instead of the variable *values*. In the code below I changed your .attr("tranform") to pass the values of d.x and d.y.

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(partitioned_data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .filter(filter_min_arc_size_text)       
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        if (computeTextRotation(d)>90&&computeTextRotation(d)<270) {
            return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + 
                   ") rotate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ",180)";
        } else {
            return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
        }
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return radius / 3 * d.depth; })    
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align  
    .text(function(d,i) {return d.name})
```